# Only the first conditions is being validated in a python function

Tags: python

```
def dice():
    import random
    print("******************************")
    print("***** DICE GENERATOR ******")
    print("******************************")

    #dice choice
    user_select=int(input("""Choose the type of dice to roll.
    (1)1d4
    (2)1d6
    (3)1d10
    (4)1d12
    (5)1d20
    :"""))
    if user_select==1:
        dice=random.randint(1,4)
        print(dice)
    return
    if user_select==2:
        dice=random.randint(1,6)
        print(dice)
    return
    if user_select==3:
        dice=random.randint(1,10)
        print(dice)
    return
    if user_select==4:
        dice=random.randint(1,12)
        print(dice)
    return
    if user_select==5:
        dice=random.randint(1,20)
        print(dice)
    return
```

in the example code above if i give the input as 1 then a random number is generated but or anything else there is no return.I  checked in the visualiser ,it is returning a None for all values except 1

Comment: Why aren't your returns inside the conditional blocks? There's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to realise that functions end if any `return` statement is reached. Functions are small pieces of code that work together on a certain job/goal. Once they are done with it they can `return` stuff or just nothing, depending on the data types you are working with and the goal of the function.

In your case you need to put only one `return` after the last `print` statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are returning straight after the first condition. I would recommend reading a book on python and understand how functions and returns work.

http://www.learnpython.org/

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, the problem is that the `return` is not within the `if` block. A common way to do what you want is to use `elif`:

```
def dice():
    import random
    print("******************************")
    print("***** DICE GENERATOR ******")
    print("******************************")

    #dice choice
    user_select=int(input("""Choose the type of dice to roll.
    (1)1d4
    (2)1d6
    (3)1d10
    (4)1d12
    (5)1d20
    :"""))
    if user_select==1:
        dice=random.randint(1,4)
    elif user_select==2:
        dice=random.randint(1,6)
    elif user_select==3:
        dice=random.randint(1,10)
    elif user_select==4:
        dice=random.randint(1,12)
    elif user_select==5:
        dice=random.randint(1,20)
    else:
        dice=None
    print(dice)
```

(edit) notice that a `return` statement is not needed at the end of a function because python will automatically return `None` here. Its harmless and some people prefer to have them.